# Python function to switch image displayed

Tags: python, image, tkinter, classification, visualization

I have a python 3 script running running on live data that calls a classification function, which returns either a 0 or a 1. What I want to have happen is for a window to display an image based on what the classifier returns.

Here is a simpler version of my classifier script:

```
from random import randint
import time

def classifier():
    time.sleep(4)
    return randint(0,1)

while True:
    classification=classifier()
```

And here is the script I have come up with so far for the visuals:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()


img1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('left.jpg'))
img2=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('right.jpg'))

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master, bg="")
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.arrow=tk.Label(self, image=img1)
        self.arrow.image=img1 #must keep this otherwise will be discarded
        self.arrow.pack()
        self.pack()


def updateImg(img):
    app.arrow.config(image=img)
    app.arrow.image=img
    app.arrow.pack()


app = Application(master=root)

app.mainloop()
```

My problem is connecting the two scripts, such that the value of classification determines the image shown in real-time. In theory I would like to be able to call updateImg from the classifier script

Comment: Assuming your image is in a Label, just update the Label to use a new image with `label_instance.config(image=new_image)`. If you want a specific answer you will have to show us a [mcve].

Comment: I've updated the question, hopefully that makes it more clear!

Answer (score 0):

It is easier when you use other code inside GUI code, then GUI code inside other code - and it is called "GUI wrapper".

Problem with GUI is that it has to run `mainloop` which works all time (till you close window) and you can't run other loops. You could use `thread` to run other loop at the same time but `tkinter` is not thread-safe and changing widgets inside other thead can make problem

You can use `root.after` to run some code periodicaly and then there is no problem with two loops because `mainloop` will run it for you.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from random import randint, randrange
import time

# --- classes ---

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master, bg="")
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        # create empty label
        self.arrow = tk.Label(self)
        self.arrow.pack()

    def update_image(self, img):
        # set image in label
        self.arrow.config(image=img)

        # because image is assigned to global list `imgs`
        # so this command may not be needed        
        self.arrow.image = img

# --- functions ---

def classifier():
    # return randint(0, len(imgs)-1) # with -1
    return randrange(0, len(imgs))   # without -1

def update_loop():
    # run your classifier from other file
    selected = classifier()

    # get image from list
    img = imgs[selected]

    # update image in window
    app.update_image(img)

    # run it again after 4000ms
    root.after(4000, update_loop)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

# list with images (create after creating `root`)
imgs = [
    ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('left.jpg')),
    ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('right.jpg')),
]    

# creacte app
app = Application(root)

# run it first time
update_loop()

# start "engine"
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately this didn't work for me at the classifier script needed to be continuously running. I got it working using threads and queue's instead, will post above

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got it working with!

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
import time
from random import randint

q=Queue() #both threads can access the queue

def GUIthread(): #all GUI actions take place in this thread
    root = tk.Tk() 
    img1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('left.jpg'))
    img2=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('right.jpg'))

    def updateImage(classification):
        if classification ==1:
            root.arrow.config(image=img2)
            root.arrow.image=img2
            root.arrow.pack()
        else:
            root.arrow.config(image=img1)
            root.arrow.image=img1
            root.arrow.pack()

    def checkQueue():
        classification=q.get()
        updateImage(classification)
        q.task_done()
        root.after(1000,checkQueue)

    root.arrow=tk.Label(image=img1)
    root.arrow.image=img1
    root.arrow.pack()          
    root.after(1, checkQueue)
    root.mainloop()


def classifier(): #mimics a thread that needs to be run continuously (collecting live data)
    while 1: 
        time.sleep(2)
        q.put(randint(0,1))


t=Thread(target=GUIthread)
t.start()
classifier()
```